# Undefined reference to a method in another class file, how to fix?

Tags: class, undefined

I've been working on a program that will do a couple of equations in regards to audio, SPL, etc.

I decided to have the main class file present the user with an option to choose what equation he wants to do, while the equations are housed in another class file.

Atm, the main class file is setup just to test maxPeakSPL(), yet I can't get it to run.

main.cpp

```
//Kh[a]os
#include "equations.h"
#include <iostream>

void mainLoop();

int maxSPL = 0;

int main()
{
std::cout << "Created by Kh[a]os" << std::endl << std::endl;
mainLoop();

return 0;
}

void mainLoop()
{

std::cout << "hi";
maxSPL = equations::maxPeakSPL();
std::cout << std::endl << maxSPL << "db" << std::endl << std::endl;


    }
```

equations.h

```
#ifndef EQUATIONS_H
#define EQUATIONS_H

#include <string>


class equations
{
    public:
        equations();
        static int maxPeakSPL();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // EQUATIONS_H
```

equations.cpp

```
#include "equations.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

equations::equations()
{

}

static int maxPeakSPL()
{

    int Sens = 0;
    double Distance = 0;
    int Watts = 0;
    int sWatts = 2;
    int eWatts = 0;
    double maxSPL = 0;
    double counter = 0;
    double wall = 0;
    std::string corner = "";

bool v = true;

    std::cout << "Sensitivity (db): " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> Sens;
    std::cout << "Amplification (watts): " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> Watts;
    std::cout << "Listening Distance (meters): " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> Distance;
    std::cout << "Distance from Wall (ft): " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> wall;
    std::cout << "Are you they in a corner? (y/n): " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> corner;


    maxSPL = Sens - (Distance*3 - 3);


while(v == true)
{
if (sWatts > Watts)
        {
            v = false;
            eWatts = sWatts;
            sWatts = sWatts/2;
            Watts = Watts-sWatts;
            counter = (double)Watts/(double)eWatts;
            counter = counter*3;
            maxSPL = maxSPL + counter;

        }

     if (v == true)
     {
        maxSPL = maxSPL + 3;
        sWatts = sWatts*2;
     }

    }
    if (wall <= 4)
    maxSPL = maxSPL + 3;

    if (corner == "Y" || corner == "YES" || corner == "y" || corner == "yes")
    maxSPL = maxSPL + 3;

    return maxSPL;

}
```

The error I get when I run it is: undefined reference to `equations::maxPeakSPL()'

I haven't a clue how to fix this, any assistance would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main, try putting the function before the main block. Include an underscore before the name of your directives/flags.

Comment: I apologize but because I am a bit novice I am not quite understanding what I should change. Are you saying:

void mainLoop();
int equations::maxPeakSPL();

Comment: No, I mean where you have the body of your void mainloop(), you need to put that before your int main() because c++ is top down.

Comment: isn't that the purpose of void mainLoop(); being declared at the top? mainLoop runs fine, everything runs, its just that one line that calls the function from the other class errors.

Comment: What you are trying to do is use a function template, but in c++ the int main() needs to be the last code block in order to use functions created in the same file.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if that is the cause of your undefined reference or not, as I have not used c++ in a long time.

Comment: btw, you are using the std class without including it as a lib and if you want to do if statements without curly braces do them on the same line.

Comment: I fixed it. I changed static int maxPeakSPL() in equations.cpp to int equations::maxPeakSPL and it worked. Why is this the case though? It seems odd to call equations:: in the equation.cpp. Is there another way I should be doing it? EDIT: the std calls work fine. EDIT2: and I did try moving it, it didn't change anything. It was still calling it in the same order. That declaration at the top tells the program to load that function first, before main. Thanks.

Comment: Because you didn't give it a type, while you were trying to use maxSPL as an int. Because that is how c++ can reference its own functions outside of the file.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the assistance xP